# Complex door hinge

Tags: hinges

[image]

How do I adjust this hinge and does it have a name?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a 2-way adjustable hinge, similar to uPVC doors & tilt & turn windows sometimes have.

The screw underneath is for height. There should/may be one for left/right adjustment inside the slot, where the top arrow is.
They sometimes have a third axis, but this one doesn't look like it does.
Sometimes, both hinges of a pair like this have independent height adjustment - in which case you need to adjust both similarly to avoid tension.

[image]